# How to set up a swagger-ui standalone server/application?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui

I would like to set up a standalone swagger-ui application, to view the different APIs from different servers in one central place.
In a second step I would like to customise swagger-ui to show multiple APIs at once.
I don't want to add swagger-ui to all the servers that provide swagger api-docs though.

To do so I would like to use spring boot and thought this should be an easy task. However, I have trouble getting it to work.

Here is what I did:

1. Generated a Spring Boot application using https://start.spring.io
2. included `spring-boot-starter-web`
3. added `io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.3.1` dependency

When opening http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html I see a 404 error and UI seems broken:

[image: swagger-ui 404]

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason for using Spring-boot instead of a simple web server for this?

See for example [here with Nginx](http://www.whiteboardcoder.com/2013/06/installing-swagger-restful-api.html), including some basic authentication (pretty old link but still looking alright), or in the ReadMe of the [swagger-ui github reposiory](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) directly for easily serving with Connect/gulp-serve inside Docker (the setup can also be reproduced directly without Docker if wanted).

Also I have no idea why you're getting resources requested by the page on a different port... Just ask in case you still need help now on this topic.